# adding a field to the form during form_validate

Tags: 7, forms

I am working on a node form in which my users can add sport-teams (which I'll handle through a taxonomy) that are related to the node (say it's a blog-entry about your local rugby-team and you want to relate it to the team's taxonomy entry). To each team entry, I also have a db-table with a corresponding zip-code of the teams headquarter (say your local rugby team comes from cardiff).

Now the users can also add teams, that are currently not in the taxonomy list (through the use of taxonomy-autocomplete (i.e. tagging)). When that happens, during `form_validate`, I fire a `form_set_error()` and ask the user to type in the City the team is coming from.

In effect, I want to add a field to the form during form_validate. But how do I do that?

I tried, to no avail, adding the following to the `$form` variable in the `form_validate` function:

```
$form['field_new_team_location'][$i] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('new team location'),
'#default_value' => $node->title,
'#size' => 60,
'#maxlength' => 128,
'#required' => TRUE,
'#description' => t('description')
);
```

**EDIT** Alas, although Charlie S' answer helped me to put up a field during validation (read: the html gets displayed; I can write in them), but it seems I cannot access it in a follow-up validation. In fact, when I hit save again, neither `$form` nor `$form_state` have the newly created fields in them! Any help accessing my fields is much appreciated!

**2nd EDIT** With what Charlie S said, it works. One thing that holding me up was that the form only gets rebuilt when no error messages are being cast. In other words, every required field has to be supplied before the form gets rebuilt and the user is able to input something in the new fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In form_validate(), make sure your arguments are being passed by reference:

```
myform_validate(&$form, &$form_state)
```

Then the last thing you should have in _validate() is:

```
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

Edit: You will want to handle the actual adding of the element in the form builder. This is tested and working:

```
function customform_custom_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form['field_a'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Field A',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 1,
  );      

  // Add field b depending on the value of field a.
  if (isset($form_state['input']) && !empty($form_state['input']['field_a'])) {
    $form['field_b'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Field B',
      '#weight' => 2,
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#weight' => 99,
  );

  return $form;
}

function customform_custom_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state['values']['field_b'])) {
    form_set_error('field_b', 'Please enter something in Field B.');
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  }
}

function customform_custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('You entered ' . $form_state['values']['field_b'] . ' for Field B.');
}
```

Comment: not exactly the complete answer, but it certainly pushed me in the right direction: I had to append my field to `$form_state['complete form']`, instead of `$form`. But apart from that, good job! thanks!

Comment: That makes sense, I will update the answer above. Glad it's working!

Comment: I am very, very sorry Charlie, but I have to revoke your answer-tag, because I have a serious follow-up question, please read the edit part of the question. thanks.

Comment: You need to have something registered for this form element when the form is first built. I will add the full code structure to my post above.

Comment: that means I have to have all the fields registered as soon as the form has been built for the first time? Or, in other words, I cannot _add_ fields, I can only make them appear to the user? That would hurt quite a bit, since then I'd have to limit the number of values the user can submit.

Comment: You can change any parameter of a field, i.e. its title, type, description, default_value, etc. You could even try only adding a field that is a fieldset and add child elements to it after validation fails. You can also add `#element_validate` parameters to elements so that you run a function to validate a specific field and don't have to worry about it in _validate() as it might not even exist (yet). Last but not least, you may just want to use the #ajax property to return updated portions of the form via JavaScript without even using _validate(): http://drupal.org/node/752056

Comment: So I just verified something, you don't even have to setup a placeholder for the element. Look at the revised code above; just add the fields in the form builder function depending on the inputted values from the user. Use _validate() to throw errors however you need and be sure to set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` and you should be good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2642/discussion-between-charlie-s-and-alex)

Comment: Sorry, had to concern myself with other things. But if you have time now, I am waiting in the chat.

Comment: Thank you for you example, but the rebuild will only happen if there are no form errors. So you need to remove the form_set_error() part and just use drupal_set_message() for you message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can actually add fields to the form on validate?
Have you looked at using ajax for this instead? You can define your own submit function and check the inputted tags here.
To make it easier, maybe you could add the field_new_team_location when you build your form and just set $form['field_new_team_location']['#access'] = FALSE and then enable it when you need it.

Comment: well, it is possible, but nonetheless your suggestions were quite creative so +1 for that!